# How to uninstall Oracle 11G software that are installed in Windows 8?

Tags: oracle, installation, windows-8

How to uninstall Oracle 11g software that are installed in Windows 8?
I have installed oracle 11g version in local machine.

Comment: please refer to oracle document https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32007/deinstall.htm#i1008369

Comment: In case standard Uninstall left something on your PC check this side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a tool called Deinstall that will remove an Oracle database as well as the Oracle software. Either GUI or command line. Check here on how to use it.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/HPCLI/oracle-deinstallation-tool-deinstall.htm

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall Oracle database on Windows follow the following steps(Non-Grid Installation only).

1) Stop the Oracle services.
[Stopping Oracle Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14316/deinstall.htm#i1008369)

2) Remove the Oracle components using Oracle Universal Installer.

> 1. Ensure that you first follow the instructions in the "Stopping Oracle Services" section.
> 2. Start Oracle Universal Installer: From the Start menu, select Programs, then Oracle - HOME_NAME, then Oracle Installation Products, and then Universal Installer.
> 3. The Welcome window for Oracle Universal Installer appears.
> 4. Click the Deinstall Products button.
> 5. The Inventory window appears.
> 6. Expand the tree of installed components until you find the components to remove.
>
> For example, if you installed a database with the Enterprise Edition option and later installed additional components with the Custom option, expand the Oracle home component to display all the components installed in the Oracle home.
>
> 7. Select the components to remove.
> 8. Click Remove.
> 9. The Confirmation window appears.
>
> In the Confirmation dialog box, click Yes to remove the selected components.
>
> Note:
>   A message may appear indicating that removing some components may cause other components to not function properly.
>   After the components are removed from your computer, the Inventory window appears without the removed components.
>
> 10 Click Close to close the Inventory window.
>
> 11. Click Cancel to exit Oracle Universal Installer.
> 12. Click Yes to confirm that you want to exit.

3) Remove Oracle Keys from the Microsoft Registry Editor.

> 1. Log in as a member of the Administrators group.
> 2. Make sure that you have stopped Oracle services.
> 3. From a command prompt, enter the following command:
>
> `SYSTEM_DRIVE:\> regedit`
>
> 4. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` and delete the `OracleHOME_NAMETNSListener` registry entry. Oracle Universal Installer automatically deletes all other Oracle Net services.
> 5. Exit the registry editor.
> 6. Restart your computer.

Reference:

[Removing Oracle Database Software](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/deinstall.htm#NTDBI006)

[Removing All Oracle Database Components](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14316/deinstall.htm#i1008369)

[Manual Oracle Uninstall](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/manual-oracle-uninstall)

Answer (score 1):

The article [Uninstalling Oracle](https://brainywit.com/how-to-uninstall-oracle-11g/) contains details on how to proceed.